# edit the form is not working

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

Merry Christmas!!!!I work with flask sqlalchemy and wtf. I could create new and would display in info.html But when I try to edit the form there is no changes in database So it is not working. So I wonder where is issues?

> app.py

```
    #With this route I can add new form in database 
    @app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def contact():
      form = LoginForm(request.form)
      if request.method == 'POST':
          if form.validate()== True:
              contact = Contacts()
              # populate the model
              form.populate_obj(contact)
              db.session.add(contact)
              db.session.commit()
              # Contact commited to database
              # RETURN TO INFO.HTML
              return redirect(url_for('info'))

           else:
              #If the form does not have all fields that are required 
              return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

    # This is the part for edit which is not working
    # so I query and populate it but no change none in 
    # database none in info.html
    @app.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods=['POST']) 
    def edit(id=None):
        user = Contacts.query.get_or_404(id)  
        form = LoginForm(request.form,obj=user) 
        # check the validate and then populate the obj  
        if form.validate_on_submit()== True:
           #populate it
           form.populate_obj(user)
           db.session.commit()
           return redirect(url_for('info'))
        else: 
            #If the form does not have all fields that are required 
            return render_template('edit.html', id=id )
    @app.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
   def profile(id=None):
  user = Contacts.query.get_or_404(id)
  form = LoginForm(request.form, obj=user)
  return render_template('edit.html',form=form, id =id)
    # this route to html that should show all info
    @app.route('/info', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def info():
        #query all
        info = Contacts.query.all()
        return render_template('info.html', contact=info)
```

> model.py

```
 # model with table name Contacts
 class Contacts(db.Model):
       __tablename__ = "Contacts"
       id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
       name = db.Column(db.String(50))
       email = db.Column(db.String(50))
       age = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

> form.py

```
# this is the form wtf
Class LoginForm(Form):
        name = StringField("Name", [validators.Required("Please enter your name.")])
        email = StringField("Email", [validators.Required("Please enter your email address."), validators.Email("Please enter valid email address.")])
        age = IntegerField("age", [validators.Required("Please enter your age.")])
        submit = SubmitField("Submit")
```

> info.html

```
 # it should display all updated form But it wont??
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block content %}
         <h2>show the info</h2>
             {% for contact in contact  %} # Maybe this is also Problem?
               <strong>name:</strong> {{ contact.name}} <br>
               <strong>email:</strong> {{ contact.email }} <br>
               <strong>age:</strong> {{ contact.age}} <br>
               <br>
               {% endfor %}

      {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Still No good answer any Help?

Comment: are the forms validating? so that you get to the part where you actually du things with sqlalchemy ?

Comment: you don't ever update when the validation is not working. since the updating only happens when when the forms are probably validated.

Comment: Thanx and I know that I mean why there is no change in database help me out with this @muthan

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to readd a Object, when you get it per query. The Queryobject is bound to the session. So you only need to `commit` the changes and not to `add` them again.

so this should be the corrected code snippet

```
user = Contacts.query.get_or_404(id)  
    form = LoginForm(request.form,obj=user) 
    # check the validate and then populate the obj  
    if form.validate()== True:
        # populate it
        form.populate_obj(user)
        db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my machine. With little modification in code I was able to update database.

Please find updated chunk below:

```py
@app.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods=['POST'])
def submit(id=None):
    user = Contacts.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = LoginForm(request.form,obj=user)
    #return render_template('edit.html', form=form, id=1 )
    if form.validate() == True:
        form.populate_obj(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('info'))
    else:
        return redirect(url_for(edit, id=id))

@app.route('/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET'])
def edit(id=None):
    user = Contacts.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = LoginForm(request.form,obj=user)
    return render_template('edit.html', form=form, id=id )
```

Comment: I try ur new one But still No change in database Any idea?@
Deepak Kumar Mangal

Comment: Maybe its not connected to database don't know But I can add new (route contact) is working So no idea @Deepak Kumar Mangal

Comment: @Linda It is working fine for me. Can you please share your full code so I can try to debug?

Comment: update it Now,really appreciate if u could help @Deepak Kumar Mangal

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question, but I'm referencing from [Why doesn't my WTForms-JSON form update correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740766/why-doesnt-my-wtforms-json-form-update-correctly).

Essentially, you need to initialize the Form first then check to see if it was submitted or not:

```
form = FormBuilder()
if not form.is_submitted():

    form = FormBuilder.populate_obj(obj)
else:
    form = FormBuilder() # will populate from submitted data

if form.validate_on_submit():
```

It helped me when having the same issues.